# How to assign page paths properly on a HTML webpage?

Tags: html, path, hyperlink

My question is basicly this:
[www.mysite.com/products](http://www.mysite.com/products) needs to show all products page and
[www.mysite.com/products/product1](http://www.mysite.com/products/product1) needs to show product1 .

But when I create a products folder and put my product.html file into it, it shows /products/ folder when trying to navigate [www.mysite.com/products](http://www.mysite.com/products).

Thank you  for your help.

I want to see products page and product1 page but not an index of folder.

Comment: when you visit an url mapped to a directory in a typical wwwroot hosted by a canonical web server, depending on how it's configured, the response will contain the directory listing. The question as asked is actually hiding behind how to build a rewrite rule or how are routes expected to be mapped to actions... but it would be too wide to answer as is

Comment: You need a server to do it, it's not related to HTML